# how to get image from gridview list when i click image, i'm using picasso library

Tags: android, gridview, android-intent, picasso

i want when i click image from gridview, image send to new layout (Details Image)

this is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Intent i = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("arg3", arg2);
            startActivity(i);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "okey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public static final String URL ="http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/";
Context mContext;
int mThumbIds = 18;
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
     return mThumbIds;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(95, 95));
   //     imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    Picasso.with(this.mContext)
    .load(URL + position +".jpg")
  //  .placeholder(R.drawable.loader).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).fit()
   .into(imageView);


  //  imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
   return imageView;
    }
// references to our images }
```

in here i try get image from gridview, i try use intent, it's not work

Details Image

```
public class SingleViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_view);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("arg3");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SingleView);


    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.getItemViewType(position));}}
```

can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

- Pass the URL of the image you selected from MainActivity to SingleViewActivity.
- Use ImageLoader, and do not modify the width/heigth otherwise the memory cache will miss.

Others the cache will do everything for you.

Comment: can you give me example ?